# Loop and Reference array's elements in a range excel macros

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have a database (table) and need to copy several specific columns to another worksheet (`sheet3`). In addition, Each column should be pasted in an specific column of `sheet3`. To accomplish this, I created two arrrays: `arrSht` contains the headers of the columns to be copied, and `Arrcol` contains the numbers that reference the columns.

Then, I try to loop through each element of both arrays to find the column, copy and paste it. My try goes as follows:

```
Sub copia()

Dim f As Range
Dim arrSht, Arrcol As Variant, j As Long

arrSht = Array("a","b","c")
Arrcol = Array(5, 6, 8)

For j = LBound(arrSht) To UBound(arrSht)    

Set f = Sheet1.Cells.Find(arrSht(j), searchorder:=xlByRows, LookAt:=xlPart) 

 If Not f Is Nothing Then
 Sheet1.Range(f, Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
             Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(2, Arrcol(j)))
 Else
 MsgBox arrSht(j) & "Header not found!"
 End If
Next j
end sub
```

To clarify, the first iteration of the loop should find the range whose header is "a" (first element of `arrSht`) and store it in `f`. Then, copy the column that `f` corresponds to. And finally paste it in `Sheet3` column 5 (i.e. the first element of `Arrcol`)

when I run the code I get the error: "Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed" in the line that corresponds to `Sheet1.Range(f, Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
                 Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(2, Arrcol(j)))`. So, I am probably referencing the array's element in the wrong way or just writing a wrong loop.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure but try changing to `Sheet1.Range(f, Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
Sheet3.Cells(2, Arrcol(j))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code...

```
Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(2, Arrcol(j)))
```

...`Sheet3.Cells(2, Arrcol(j))` is returning a `Range`.  You're then passing that to `Sheet3.Range` as a parameter.

Since you only care about 1 cell, skip the `.Range` call and just use the `.Cells`:

```
Sheet3.Cells(2, Arrcol(j))
```